# Get ViewCell's model in constructor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

There are some questions without any real answer for this use case:

> How can I retrieve the current `ViewCell`'s model in its constructor?

What I'd like to have access, for instance, to the background of the cell, specified in the model.

I have tried many solutions, like binding string properties to fake `Label` objects inside the cell, but both in the constructor and in the `OnAppearing` method they are `null`.

For example, let's say I have a custom cell that needs to display a title, a description, and an **optional** icon. If the icon resource string is empty, it will display a default one:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}


public class CustomCell : ViewCell
{
    public CustomCell()
    {
        StackLayout cell = new StackLayout();

        StackLayout text = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
        };

        Label titleLabel = new Label();
        Label descriptionLabel = new Label();

        titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "title");
        descriptionLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "description");

        Image image = new Image();

        // Custom icon
        if (titleLabel.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(???);
        }
        else
        {
            image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("myproject.icons.default.png");
        }

        text.Children.Add(titleLabel);
        text.Children.Add(descriptionLabel);
        cell.Children.Add(text);
        cell.Children.Add(image);

        View = cell;
    }
}
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Not understanding too much, could you please show code to explain which is you want?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I've edited the question with a code I'd like to be able to write.

Comment: `var model = CustomCell.BindingContext as ListItem` Is this your want?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT yes, but if I use `var model = BindingContext as ListItem`, then I get `null`. Note that I had to modify your code because the compiler complained about static members.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom view cell that takes arguments or model in its constructor like this

```
public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public Bar bar;
    pulic CustomViewCell(Foo foo)
    {
       bar = foo;
    }

    public GetCurrentModel()
    {
       return bar;
    }
}
```